# How do I grep a string from lines that contain a certain number?

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a very long file with lines with multiple columns of numbers -- more than 3 columns per each line except for one line. It's a very large file, and I'm trying to locate a line that has `13` only. Since it's a big file, when I grep `13`, I get many many lines with numbers that have `13` somewhere in them. How can I use `grep` such that only lines containing `13` with `wc=1` are returned?

Comment: Regex? ``grep "^13$"``

Comment: @user996142 oh, okay, that works

Comment: Regular expressions are usefull: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep(1)` has an option to search for only entire lines that match a specified regexp:

```
 -x, --line-regexp
         Only input lines selected against an entire fixed string or
         regular expression are considered to be matching lines.
```

Assuming that the lines you want to match contain no whitespace, the command:

```
grep -x 13
```

will provide the output you're seeking.

OTOH, if the lines you seek to match do contain leading and/or trailing whitespace, then you need a more complex pattern:

```
grep -x '[[:blank:]]*13[[:blank:]]*'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Wouldn't that be a problem if the line has space characters?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate Yes, the answer mentions that.  I've made an edit to handle the case where the line does contain whitespace.